After deploying the backend server on Firebase Functions, errors occur in Google Analytics
The backend is configured with Node.js and the front end uses Vite.
We distributed what we were developing locally to Firebase Functions.
I thought there would be no problem because I used a Google Cloud Service account in the existing local area, but the API using Google Analytics alone causes 500 errors.
The following errors occur on the server terminal.
>  Error during visitor stats fetch: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
>      at callErrorFromStatus (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:193:76)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
>      at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
>      at /Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:129:78
>      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
>  for call at
>      at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:161:32)
>      at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
>      at /Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/@google-analytics/data/build/src/v1beta/beta_analytics_data_client.js:233:29
>      at /Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
>      at OngoingCallPromise.call (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
>      at NormalApiCaller.call (/Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
>      at /Users/user/Documents/dev/works/project-backend/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:112:30
>      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
>    code: 7,
>    details: 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.',
>    metadata: Metadata {
>      internalRepr: Map(4) {
>        'endpoint-load-metrics-bin' => [Array],
>        'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array],
>        'google.rpc.errorinfo-bin' => [Array],
>        'grpc-status-details-bin' => [Array]
>      },
>      options: {}
>    },
>    statusDetails: [
>      ErrorInfo {
>        metadata: [Object],
>        reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
>        domain: 'googleapis.com'
>      }
>    ],
>    reason: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT',
>    domain: 'googleapis.com',
>    errorInfoMetadata: {
>      method: 'google.analytics.data.v1beta.BetaAnalyticsData.RunReport',
>      service: 'analyticsdata.googleapis.com'
>    }
>  }

When I developed it local, I didn't have any rights issues, so I thought there would be no errors when I deployed it to Firebase Functions.

As you can see in the picture, only visor-stats (APIs using Google Analytics) are experiencing 500 errors.

I didn't know the problem, so I added the authority.

I am using the service account and downloaded it in json format, and I entered the file path correctly in the .env file.
Is there a new permission setting that I need to do?
Of course, Google Analytics API and Google Analytics Data API are in use.
I'd appreciate it if you could help me. ㅠㅠ
I am conducting a local test with the command below.
firebase emulators:start --only functions

The functions/index.js code is as follows.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = require('./app');

// 환경 변수 설정
dotenv.config();

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    });
}

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

functions/app.js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const swaggerSetup = require('./src/config/swagger');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const requestRoutes = require('./src/routes/requestRoutes');
const cors = require('cors');

dotenv.config();

const authRoutes = require('./src/routes/authRoutes');
const blogRoutes = require('./src/routes/blogRoutes');
const projectRequestRoutes = require('./src/routes/projectReqRoutes');
const visitorStatsRoutes = require('./src/routes/visitorStatsRoutes');
const bakRoutes = require('./src/routes/bakRoutes');
const authController = require('./src/controllers/authController');

const app = express();

// CORS 설정
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:5173', 'https://yinvl-web.web.app'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true,  // 인증 정보(쿠키 등) 포함 여부
}));

app.options('*', cors()); // Preflight 요청을 위한 CORS 설정

// Morgan 로깅 구성
const morganFormat = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'combined' : 'dev';
app.use(morgan(morganFormat));

// Express 설정: JSON 및 URL-encoded 페이로드 처리
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Cookie Parser
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));

// Session configuration
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET, // 세션 암호화 키
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true, // javascript에서 접근 못하도록 (보안에 좋음)
        secure: true
    }
}));

// Initialize Passport
app.use(authController.initializePassport);
app.use(authController.session);

// Routes
app.use('/', authRoutes);  // 로그인 및 인증 라우트
app.use('/project-requests', projectRequestRoutes);  // 고객의 프로젝트 요청 폼
app.use('/yinvl/blog', blogRoutes);  // 블로그 관련 라우트
app.use('/yinvl', requestRoutes);  // 어드민 대시보드에서 요청 조회
app.use('/yinvl', visitorStatsRoutes);  // 방문자 통계 관련 라우트
app.use('/yinvl', bakRoutes);  // 백업 관련 라우트

// Swagger API 문서화 설정
swaggerSetup(app);

module.exports = app;

